# Скачивание файла с помощью CURL

Tags: php, curl

Доброго дня. Пытаюсь при помощи curl и библиотеки simple html dom скачать файл со страницы сайта nnm-club.me. С авторизацией и получением целевой страницы проблем не возникло, сделал это с помощью следующего кода:

```
$url = "http://nnm-club.me/forum/login.php";
$referer = "http://nnm-club.me/forum/";
$user_agent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)";
$post = "username=User&password=12345&redirect=&login=%C2%F5%EE%E4";
$header [] = "Accept: text/html, application/xml;q=0.9, application/xhtml+xml, image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, */*;q=0.1";
$header [] = "Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en;q=0.8";
$header [] = "Accept-Charset: Windows-1251, utf-8, *;q=0.1";
$header [] = "Accept-Encoding: deflate, identity, *;q=0";
$user_cookie = "cookies.txt";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $user_cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $user_cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $_POST['url']);
$page = curl_exec($ch);
$pageContent = str_get_html($page);
```

Далее нахожу на странице ссылку вида "домен/forum/download.php?id=766709", и вот как раз по ней хочу скачать файл. Запуск нового сеанса curl по данному адресу с настройкой CURLOPT_FILE не дает должного результата, поскольку, если я всё правильно понимаю, там происходит несколько редиректов и присваивание каких-то дополнительных ID.  Мой скудный опыт работы с curl и в целом с php не позволяет мне более грамотно изложить проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня был подобный вопрос когда-то.
Можно после загрузки первой страницы, парсить с помощью RegExp  полученную страницу вместе с хедером curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,true); выбирать оттуда referer и т.д.,
Так же можно в браузере посмотреть,  через например, FireBug(Firefox) Какие заголовки добавляет и что отправляет серверу для скачивания.
И потом выбирать эти данные с помощью CURL и добавлять их к Запросу на скачивание.
Тоесть, грубо говоря, получил данные с первой страницы, отпарсил например регекспами, нашёл линк нужный добавил новые заголовки, вызвал CURL, получил опять заголовки отпарсил, вызвал уже CURL для файла. Сохранил, в твоем случае нужно CURL вызывать три раза с новыми параметрами. Или если там есть именно редирект ( я вижу ты тут его включил curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);), то тогда два запуска CURL

Comment: curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,true); Включает возврат хедера

Comment: Тоесть по сути тебе нужно проанализировать что отсылает и что принимает, я это делаю обычно в FIREFOX